# How to use variable in xsl?

Tags: xml, xslt

I create an XSL like below:

```
<xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="range_from &lt; 0 and range_to > 5">
      <xsl:variable name="markup_03" select="((7 div $total_price_02) * 100)"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="range_from &lt; 6 and range_to > 10">
      <xsl:variable name="markup_03" select="((5 div $total_price_02) * 100)"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:variable name="markup_03" select="0"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
<xsl:variable name="total_price_03" select="(($total_price_02 * $markup_03) div 100) + $total_price_02"/>
```

I am getting the following error:

> A reference to variable or parameter 'markup_03' cannot be resolved.
>   The variable or parameter may not be defined, or it may not be in
>   scope

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring the `markup_03` inside of the `<xsl:choose>` conditions, so it is not in scope when you are attempting to reference it outside of the `<xsl:choose>`.

Instead, declare your `<xsl:variable name="markup_03">` and nest the `<xsl:choose>` inside of the variable to determine what value to assign to it:

```
    <xsl:variable name="markup_03">
       <xsl:choose>
           <xsl:when test="range_from &lt; 0 and range_to > 5">
               <xsl:value-of select="((7 div $total_price_02) * 100)"/>
           </xsl:when>
           <xsl:when test="range_from &lt; 6 and range_to > 10">
               <xsl:value-of select="((5 div $total_price_02) * 100)"/>
           </xsl:when>
           <xsl:otherwise>
               <xsl:value-of select="0"/>
           </xsl:otherwise>
       </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="total_price_03" select="(($total_price_02 * $markup_03) div 100) + $total_price_02"/>
```